# Backtrace statistics for heap allocations - where is it called from and how many times?

Tags: c++, c, statistics, malloc, new-operator

I would need to know from which places in my program is a `malloc`/`new` called and, for each such a distinct place, **how many times**. Something as a *top-down* function call analysis with respect to memory allocations.

Is there any tool that gathers such statistics? (`malloc`/`new` are mostly invoked via `std::vector` member functions.)

Comment: If you are on Linux, valgrind will help. Otherwise, maybe use a profiler like gprof and grep in the output for malloc/free?

Comment: How exactly can I use Valgrind or gprof to find out the number of `malloc`/`new` calls from a particular source code place? Or, better, to find out hotspots, i.e., source code places from which most memory allocations occur?

Comment: For valgrind, maybe suppressions may help pinpint suspected areas of code. But probably, a profiler is better.

Comment: Which profiler? I've tried gprof and Intel VTune, but didn't see the statistics I'm looking for.

Comment: Been a while since I used gprof, but can't you generate a call graph from it? Maybe using gviz as a helper?

Comment: And do these call graphs contain the counts of function calls?

Comment: So something like this is not similar to what you want? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/wrkshp50/805-4947/6j4m8jrn7/index.html Otherwise, you may have to do some parsing of gprof output yourself, maybe using perl.

Comment: I just found out that Valgrind does exactly what I need. Namely, with the Callgrind tool and visualization in Kcachegrind or Qcachegrind, it shows me call graphs with the number of calls by each edge. Thanks anyway for help and suggestions.

Comment: Good that valgrind/callgrind plus visualizations fit the bill, thx for the update.

Comment: if you use Visual Studio,try [vld](https://vld.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that Valgrind does exactly what I need. Namely, with the Callgrind tool and visualization in Kcachegrind or Qcachegrind, it shows me call graphs with the number of calls by each edge. Hopefully this will help also someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The debug versions of most C++ runtimes offer some level of debug hooks to assist with allocations etc.

A more customisable alternative is to write your own `operator new` and `operator delete` etc. to provide the functionality you desire (e.g. accepting file, line and function names as arguments and with the counting and logging done internally). Hooking these up with the preprocessor `__FILE__`,`__LINE__` etc. and, for convenience, a macro to substitute `new` and `delete` (ATL/MFC uses this technique).

If the focus is on a single container, the best is simply to write your own allocator and create the `vector` with that.

```
std::vector<int, MyAllocator> my_vector;
// or...
using MyVector = std::vector<int, MyAllocator>;
MyVector my_vector;
```

---

Sample idea to replace the `new` and `delete`;

```
void* operator new(std::size_t count, int line, char const* file)
{
    auto p = ::malloc(count);
    std::printf("Allocate new @ %s:%d (%p)\n", file, line, p);
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void* pointer) noexcept
{
    std::printf("Deallocate pointer (%p)\n", pointer);
    ::free(pointer);
}

#define NEWIT new (__LINE__, __FILE__)
#define new NEWIT

int main()
{
    //auto p = new (__LINE__, __FILE__) int{};
    auto p = new int{};
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: I have many different vectors, so a custom allocator would require a lot of code changes. How can I write such a custom `new` operator? I would need to find out backtrace there and increment some counter for each distinct bt. This solution came to my mind, but I wonder if there is a tool for this task.

Comment: @DanielLangr. I've added a sample of what the code (could) look like. You would need to expand it and place it appropriately in the code (typically at the top of the cpp file) to get the results through-out the code base. You would also look to put the `new` and `delete` in their own cpp file as well.

Comment: Given the comments you made on the "hotspot" concerns, I would also look to the profiler on your platform as well.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help. Between my code and `new` is typically like 5 to 10 nested function calls. E.g., implementation of Libstdc++ vectors consists of lot of nested calls. And the `new` is hidden somewhere deep inside. I need to find corresponding lines in my code, not in STL implementations.

Comment: Which profiler? I've tried gprof and VTune, but did not find the number of calls to `new` or `malloc` there. It just tells me how much time is spent within.

Comment: @DanielLangr. I have no particular recommendations on the tool here. Another idea is to enlist the code from a memory leak checker that targets your platform, you can modify the code for it to get the results you are looking for. Basically the code needed to locate memory leaks is the same as the code you desire, the output and post processing will be specific as well.

Comment: I just found out that Valgrind does exactly what I need. Namely, with the Callgrind tool and visualization in Kcachegrind or Qcachegrind, it shows me call graphs with the number of calls by each edge. Thanks anyway for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[Open|SpeedShop](http://openspeedshop.org/) tool can make a memory trace analysis. The data it provides is described in [User Manual](http://openspeedshop.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/OpenSpeedShop_User_Manual_v22_microsoft_pc_standardsize.pdf), page 96. It seem to provide the call path and the number of calls. 
Please note that Open|SpeedShop can be difficult to build. [Here's](https://openspeedshop.org/docs/users_guide/BuildAndInstallGuide.html) a build guide, note the list of perquisites packages for your OS. You'd need to build "CBTF" version to enable memory trace analysis.

Comment: I just found out that Valgrind does exactly what I need. Namely, with the Callgrind tool and visualization in Kcachegrind or Qcachegrind, it shows me call graphs with the number of calls by each edge. Thanks anyway for help and suggestions.